# X11 forwarding on Yosemite

Tags: macos, ssh, x11

X11 forwarding has stopped working since I upgraded to Yosemite. I tried reinstalling XQuartz, but that did not solve the problem. Has anyone faced the same problem?

EDIT:
I was finally able to fix the problem.

```
launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist
```

Comment: X11 forwarding is working fine for me. I did a clean install of Yosemite, perhaps that made a difference.